# How can I loop trough 3 input fields and focus each one on click? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 input fields and a button. When I press the button I want to focus the first one, and when I press again, focus the second one and the same for the third one. But when I reach the third one I want to jump again at the first input and so on. A loop or something. I hope someone can help me

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to post your code as a [mcve] before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

this is a rather simple task that can be performed in many ways I propose one of them:

```js
let counter = 0;
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('input')[counter].focus()
  counter = (counter === 2) ? 0 : ++counter;
});
```

```html
<input type='text'>
<input type='text'>
<input type='text'>
<button>press me</button>
```

Use a counter that changes based on the clicks you've made, and resets to the maximum selected input

Reference:

- [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) / [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)